# Whether or not to integrate by parts an integral containing a derivative before solving it numerically

Tags: integration

I am estimating the derivative of an integral numerically. I believe that solving the integral by parts first before taking the derivative gives a more stable numerical result. However, I have some issues with the integration by parts, which I hope you can help me with.

The expression is as follows $\int^a_b s^r \frac{\partial f(\frac{s+k}{\exp(t)})}{\partial{k}} \text{d}s$, where $f(\cdot)$ is a continuous pdf in $R_+$ (e.g., lognormal), and $a, b >0$ are the lower and upper limits of the density. The derivative of $f(\cdot)$ is w.r.t. a marginal change in the parameter $k$. We can assume that $r, k$ and $t$ are positive.

Although I can solve this integral directly numerically ($f(\cdot)$ and all the parameters are known), since the interval $[a,b]$ is fairly large, $s^r$ becomes quickly (e.g., for $r = 3$) a huge number (potentially) creating numerical issues.

Therefore, the first step would be to redefine the integration variable from $s$ to $x$, to obtain $\int u(x) v(x) dx$, and then integrating the new expression by parts. So, I set $x = \frac{s+k}{\exp(t)}$, implying that $s = x\cdot \exp(t) - k$, and $\frac{\partial f(\frac{s+k}{\exp(t)})}{\partial{k}} = \frac{1}{\exp(t)}f^\prime(\frac{s+k}{\exp(t)})=$ $\frac{1}{\exp(t)}f^\prime(x)$. The integral, then becomes: $$\int^{\frac{a+k}{\exp(t)}}_{\frac{b+k}{\exp(t)}} (x\cdot \exp(t) - k)^r \cdot \frac{1}{\exp(t)} \cdot \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \text{d}x.$$

Integrating by parts yields, $a^r f(\frac{a+k}{\exp(t)}) - b^r f(\frac{b+k}{\exp(t)}) - \int^{\frac{a+k}{\exp(t)}}_{\frac{b+k}{\exp(t)}} r\cdot(x\cdot \exp(t) - k)^{(r-1)}  f(x) \text{d}x.$

This integration should be more stable numerically, because the interval is much smaller (the division by $\exp{t}$ helps in this sense - think about $b=0$ and $a = 1000000$, and $t = 10$). Does this reasoning make sense to you, or would there be an easier/better/more correct way to take this integration? Thank you.

Comment: This question would be better asked on math.SE since its _statistical_ relevance is small.

Comment: Consider analyzing the integrand by computing its the Taylor series of its logarithm around its maximum in $[a,b].$  This is the basis of saddlepoint approximations in statistics and, even if it happens not to be directly applicable, can provide insight into numerical stability, normalization, and so on.